# ionic can not found module @angular/fire/storage/storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to know what version of AngularFireStorage i install. Because im using someone code and its using AngularFireStorage and also please how ill import.

```
"rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
"firebase": "^4.13.1",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
```

app.module.ts

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorageModule, AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';
```

can not find module angularfire2/storage

Answer (score 0):

> **Support for firebase storage was added in `5.0.0-rc.6`.**

**Therefore, you need to update the angularfire2 dependency, in order to use firebase storage.**

`npm install firebase angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.11 --save`

`import { AngularFireStorageModule } from 'angularfire2/storage';`

```
 @NgModule({
  imports: [ AngularFireStorageModule ]
 })
```

**package.json**

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
"firebase": "^5.1.0",
"rxjs": "^6.1.0",
```

[**Repo**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/releases/tag/5.0.0-rc.6) [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1701#issuecomment-394079180)

**Hope this is helpful!**

Comment: Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface 'FirebaseApp'. Property 'automaticDataCollectionEnabled' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'.
 showing this error

Comment: @UmaizKhan Update to `npm install firebase angularfire2@next --save` solution [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1338#issuecomment-385207140)

Comment: now Module '"C:/Users/ionic/Desktop/mobilemobile/freshapp/node_modules/firebase/index"' has no exported member 'functions'.

Comment: try with     "@angular/fire": "^5.1.0",
    "firebase": "^5.5.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",  its showing error TypeError: util.isBrowser is not a function

Comment: Note `@angular/fire` is the new package and is the one that should be used but then the import paths will change from like `angularfire2/storage` to `@angular/fire/storage` and you don't need `rxjs-compat` if you have `rxjs` of same version. If you want to go with the present package i.e. `@angular/fire` you need to use the right import paths

Comment: And also you can mark the answer as accepted as it adheres to your original question `can not find module angularfire2/storage` for miss-matching package you have to find the right versions as per your app dependencies or you need to upgrade to the latest stable version with proper imports and Install using `npm install firebase @angular/fire --save`